# Windows 8 mail app wont autosync - keeps asking for lock screen permissions

Tags: windows-8, email, permissions, sync

I did a fresh installation of windows 8.1 on my new asus n550jv, and since a few days ago i noticed i would not recieve any new mails. when i went to check the settings i found out that the sync option was set to manual and there is a red sentence saying: to enable auto sync go to permissions and enable lock screen. So i did went to permissions and the lock screen was already enabled.

I tried disabling and reenabling sereval times, restarting the mail app, restarting the pc, and nothing works. I still asks me to enable lock screen even though it is enabled and it wont let me autosync.

Any ideas?
I did run the windows 8 app troubleshooting software and it didnt work.

Thanks

Update: problem solved using sfc /scannow

Answer (score 0):

problem solved by running sfc /scannow